# Force "Name" field in SP13 Library to be equal to '"Title"

Tags: 2013, column, file-upload, library, sharepoint-fields

As I understand, SP13 searches documents by document Title. 
When you upload some document to the library, you have to fill in "Name" and "Title" ( the same field twice).

What I want to do is to make these fields source values from each other. 
Is there some solution available? May be some jquery code in CE?

Comment: maybe I didn't understand right what you need but can't you use acalculate value with the  formula NAME=TITLE ?

Comment: @Gyonder Title field is Default one, I can change nothing there, and filed Name is not visible in the list of columns in library settings

Answer (score 1):

You can write up a simple workflow on Item Creation and Item Updation to set the **Name** field to be equal to **Title**.

Example in SP Designer Workflow:

Set **Current Item:Name** to **Current Item:Title**

Answer (score 1):

I put a little jQuery snippet on the Edit form for the document library that populates the Title field with the file name, if it's opening the Edit form during the initial upload process:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('EditForm.aspx?Mode=Upload') > -1) {
        $('input[id^="Title"]').val($('input[id^="FileLeafRef"]').val());
    }
});
```

This only happens on the initial upload, so users could subsequently change the value of either field, so it's not enforcing them to be in sync, but it does start them off in the right direction.